# SystemVerilog: How to merge 2 arrays into one array?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I try this code but when i compile it, i receive this error:

```
Illegal assignment pattern. The number of elements (2) doesn't match with the type's width (16)
```

.

```
module(output [15:0] O);
  reg [7:0] a, b;
  assign O = {a, b};
endmodule
```

when i compile the code with quartus i dont receive any errors, but Modelsim gives me this error.

Comment: In this code you missed name of the module. If you provided full your code maybe this is reason, why you get the error

Comment: This works fine for me after adding module name.

Answer (score 2):

You missed adding the module name and hence the error. 
Adding the module name should fix it -

```
module M (output [15:0] O);
  reg [7:0] a, b;
  assign O = {a, b};
endmodule
```